# RegEx matches if newline is included, but should not match

Tags: regex, perl

Strange behaviour in perl.
Given a regular Expression ($reg) which matches on "Beginning" then "1" or "2" and then "End" also matches on "1\n" - why?

```
my $reg='^[1-2]$';
my $x="1\n";
if ($x =~ m/$reg/) {
    print "matches";
} else {
    print "doesn't match";
}
```

if i do two newlines in $x it doesn't match any longer.
I'm looking for a code, which doesn't match the above. It should only be true, when "1" or "2" is in $x. Only RegEx is allowed - no chomp or other comparison/substition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` matches an optional linefeed. 
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

```
$        Match the end of the string (or before newline at the end
         of the string)
```

It won't match a double linefeed though.

You probably want:

```
my $reg='\A[1-2]\z';
```

Which will:

```
\A  Match only at beginning of string
\Z  Match only at end of string, or before newline at the end
\z  Match only at end of string
```

Edit: As mentioned in comments by mpapec:

Given you've got a static pattern you're matching, potentially multiple times - you're doing needless work, because the interpreter is compiling your regular expression each time it checks it.

You can compile a static pattern using `qr` which saves this processing.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators

```
my $reg = qr/\A[12]\z/;

if ( $x =~ $reg ) { 
    #...
}
```

That's particularly applicable if you're testing the same pattern a lot (especially if it's a complicated pattern).

Answer (score 0):

`^[1-2]$'` matches `1\n` because `$` (end of the line anchor) matches before the `\n` character.

Comment: it does the right thing of not matching the vertical spaces. That is it won't consider the vertical spaces (`\r` or `\f`)